# TFS 2010 - does the administration console on the build controller supposed to see all the agents?

Tags: team-foundation-server, controller, agent

We've recently migrated our TFS 2008 to TFS2010 and we wanted to have more than one build agent.

***Disclaimer: lame geek naming comming...***

So, the new server is the build controller (let's call him Captain Picard), it also has one build agent on it (let's call him Commander Data). In the Team Foundation Server Adminitration Console, in the Build Configuration, I see the controller and the agent I created.

Then, on another machine, I install the build services. I configure it to use the Captain Picard controller and I create an agent (let's call it Commander Riker).

Now, on the build controller administration console, in the Build Configuration, should I see the Commander Riker agent? Because I don't. I know it works, because if I disable Commander Data, Commander Riker builds instead. But I still don't see it in the administration console on the controller.

This is the administration console from the controler (Captain Picard and Commander Data): https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaLgo.jpg

This is the administration console from the build service server (commander riker): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTjF6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You only see what you installed on any particular machine. Since the controller is remote, it doesn't appear /w Riker.

here is a good overview of all the possible combinations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793166.aspx